# Jquery Smart Wizard freezing up

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, smart-wizard

I'm using IE 8 and the jquery smart wizard version 3.2.0. I've noticed when enclose the smart wizard within an additional `<div>` tag (with the intent of displaying the wizard within a jquery dialog popup), the wizard will not advance steps when a function is specified  for the onLeaveStep event.

And now for the code:

The javascript setting up the wizard:

```
$('#wizard').smartWizard({ transitionEffect: 'slideleft', onLeaveStep: leaveAStepCallback, onFinish: onFinishCallback});
```

Simple functions associated with the events for the wizard:

```
  // wizard functions
function leaveAStepCallback(obj) {
    // Get current step
    var step_num = obj.attr('rel'); // get the current step number
}
function onFinishCallback() {
    alert('Finish Called');
}
function showStep(obj) {
    // Get current step
    var step_num = obj.attr('rel'); // get the current step number
}
```

And the HTML markup (I removed the step content within the `<p>` tags for brevity - this resulted it the same lack of functionality as if there was content within, so that can be ruled out)

```
<div id="wizDialog">

<div id="wizard" class="swMain">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#step-1">
            <label class="stepNumber">1</label>
            <span class="stepDesc">
               Step 1<br />
               <small>Step 1 - </small>
            </span>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-2">
            <label class="stepNumber">2</label>
            <span class="stepDesc">
               Step 2<br />
               <small>Step 2 - </small>
            </span>
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-3">
            <label class="stepNumber">3</label>
            <span class="stepDesc">
               Step 3<br />
               <small>Step 3 - </small>
            </span>                   
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-4">
            <label class="stepNumber">4</label>
            <span class="stepDesc">
               Step 4<br />
               <small>Step 4 - </small>
            </span>                   
            </a></li>

            <li><a href="#step-5">
            <label class="stepNumber">5</label>
            <span class="stepDesc">
               Step 5<br />
               <small>Step 5 - </small>
            </span>                   
            </a></li>     
            <li><a href="#step-6">
            <label class="stepNumber">6</label>
            <span class="stepDesc">
               Step 6<br />
               <small>Step 6 - </small>
            </span>                   
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-7">
            <label class="stepNumber">7</label>
            <span class="stepDesc">
               Step 7<br />
               <small>Step 7 - </small>
            </span>                   
            </a></li>
            <li><a href="#step-8">
            <label class="stepNumber">8</label>
            <span class="stepDesc">
               Step 8<br />
               <small>Step 8 - </small>
            </span>                   
            </a></li>                       
        </ul>
        <div id="step-1">   
        <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 1 Content</h2>
            <p>
            </p>                                
        </div>
        <div id="step-2">
        <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 2 Content</h2>   
            <p>
            </p>        
        </div>                      
        <div id="step-3">
        <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 3 Content</h2>   
            <p>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="step-4">
        <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 4 Content</h2>   
            <p>
                </p>

        </div>
        <div id="step-5">
        <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 5 Content</h2>   
            <p>
            </p>

        </div>
        <div id="step-6">
        <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 6 Content</h2>   
            <p>
                </p>

        </div>
        <div id="step-7">
        <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 7 Content</h2>   
            <p>

            </p>

        </div>
        <div id="step-8">
        <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 8 Content</h2>   
            <p>
            </p>

        </div>    

</div>
</div>
```

Has anyone had similar results with this? Or have an explanation why the wizard will not work when nested within additional `<div>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

onLeaveStep requires that you return a boolean value.  Return true and you will be able to advance through the wizard.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to have worked, but the elements in the steps seems to be unavailable (textbox, radiobuttons). I can put focus on the elements, but it won't accept any input from the keyboard.